# Extend navigation bar under status bar in interface building

Tags: ios, interface-builder

The navigation bar renders as it should when running on the simulator, because I'm implementing the delegate method.

```
extension AboutViewController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
   func positionForBar(bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
      return .TopAttached
   }
}
```

But I want it to look the same when rendered in interface builder. How do I do that?

[image]

[image]

### Edit

Here's the editor menu, there's no pin option there.

[image]

Comment: Do you want that there'd be a gap between navigation bar and top of the screen?

Comment: No, that's exactly what I **don't** want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding top constraint to `Top Layout Guide`, select navigation bar in Interface Builder and go to `Editor > Pin > Top Space to Superview`.

Suddenly in Xcode 7 there's no `Pin` menu. So try do that (see the screenshot).

[image]

Comment: It's already embedded, but I wan't to have a custom navigation bar, not the one created by the navigation controller.

Comment: Why you want that? You can customize bar created by controller as well in code.

Comment: I can't customise it differently per each view controller. Either way, this is not answering my question, you're just changing the premise.

Comment: Remove Top Layout Guide constraint and check updated answer, hope it will work.

Comment: I've updated my question with a screenshot of my Editor menu, there's no pin item there. This is Xcode 7 beta 5.

Comment: You can do this in code in `viewDidLoad` method 

    `view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: navBar, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))`

Comment: This has not effect to how the navigation bar looks in interface builder. I'm so confused right now...

Comment: Because your code affects user interface after being compiled, so changes can't be seen in Interface Builder because basically it is just xml document.

Comment: Dude, interface builder is NOT an xml document, files with *.storyboard* extensions are `xml` documents of type `com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB`. Interface Builder is a part of the Xcode toolchain. And I want to have a 1-to-1 map in terms of compiled UI and IB UI. My question only has to do with how stuff renders in IB and not anywhere else.

Comment: I didn't mean that Interface Builder is a `.xml` document, I meant your `.xib` is a `.xml`. Sorry for vague comment.

Comment: No worries dude, the part I'm still confused with if you can make this happen. Navigation controller does it, so it must be possible to do it on your own.

Comment: I found another solution, try it, I can't currently test it on Xcode 7.

Comment: This does not effect the height of the nav bar, it only changes it's position. The key desire here is for the nav bar to extend under the status bar, not change it's position.